# Embedded object saves without error, but does not show in mongo. How can this be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have:

```
Tree
  embeds_one :branch

Branch
  embedded_in :tree

b = Branch.create(tree=t).save
```

which returns true 
and b.id returns a long bsonid

Then I do:

```
Branch.all.first
```

which returns nil

How can this be?

ALSO,

I remove the embeds_one, embedded_in relationship and it all saves to mongo fine.

What is going on?

Comment: `Tree.first` -- what does that return?

Comment: If branch is embedded, then it's not independently queryable. (Unless I'm misunderstanding what you've got)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I needed to embed using a new object, as you can clearly see, I'm not embedding with a new object, im referencing an existing one t.

Comment: My point is that if you embed the `Branch` in `Tree`, it's embedded in a MongoDb document, and there isn't a standard way in MongoDb to do the query you're trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You have to create an object from Tree then create an object from Branch through the Tree object you created, the code should be:

```
t = Tree.first || Tree.create
b = t.branch.create
```

Answer (score 0):

alter the `Tree` model

```
embeds_one  :branch, cascade_callbacks: true
```

as stated by the [docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html)

> If you want the embedded document callbacks to fire when calling a persistence operation on its parent, you will need to provide the cascade callbacks option to the relation.

also one other thing to note:
the embedded models cannot be queried on their own (as mentioned by @WiredPrairie)... only from the parent model, so

```
Branch.first # will always return nil
Tree.first.branch # will return the embedded branch if found
```

this point is a matter of self preference - you can ignore it - of the following syntax.

```
t.branch.create!(branch_attr) # or
t.branch.create(branch_attr).save
# i found both those syntaxes used more.
```

over

```
b = Branch.create(tree=t).save
```